# Linux Ubuntu grub installation error, embedding area

Tags: grub2, system-installation

Trying to fresh install Ubuntu over an existing Windows install. At the end of the install, I get an error pop-up:

```
    Boost.Python error in job "bootloader".
    
    Command 'grub-install --target=i386-pc --recheck --force /dev/sda' returned non-zero exit status 1. Installing for i386-pc platform. grub-install: warning: your embedding area is unusually small. core.img won't fit in it.. grub-install: error: embedding is not possible, but this is required for cross-disk install.
    
    Traceback:
    
    File "usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/calamares/modules/bootloader/main.py", line 486, in run prepare_bootloader(fw_type)
    
    File "usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/calamares/modules/bootloader/main.py", line 458, in prepare_bootloader install_grub(efi_directory, fw_type)
    
    File "usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/calamares/modules/bootloader/main.py", line 363, in install_grub check_target_env_call([libcalamares.job.configuration["grubInstall"],
    
    File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was installing from an external hard drive as I didn't have a pen drive. The bootloader settings at the bottom of the install dialog when setting up the partitioning were set to be installed to the external hard drive. I changed this to the internal drive (where Ubuntu was being installed) and it worked.